# How to get the "input" field value inside a EventListener function from DOM in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Inside my "characters" component I have a form with a textfield, and button. ->
[image]

When I click the button it registers, and enters the function but I have no idea how to grab the current input text and use it in the called async function.

**HTML:**
[image]

**TS:**
[image]

Sadly getting the promptText does not work. I have the feeling I am missing a core concept of angular here, but even after extensive search, no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the HTML you included here the contents of `characters.component.html` file?

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu Yes it is :)

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu The value i get from the red marked TS is just "null" sadly

Comment: Can I ask why are you using angular if you try to do everything the vanilla way? Why not jQuery, or plain javascript?

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu Because this is a small personal project to learn and prepare for a angular job i got in a few months. So i like to do the angular way, but sadly not much guidance

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu I have no problems with rewriting this if you can point me in the right direction with a link or so :D

Comment: The internet is full of resources. I believe you need to work on your search engine usage skills. I suggest you to go through the tour of heroes first, then try to build your own app: https://angular.io/tutorial. Don't skip anything, even if it looks too easy, and most important: write the whole code in your own project. Don't copy paste anything, don't download any sources, don't clone any github repo. Just do it yourself.

Comment: You could do both of them; [the store](https://angular.io/start) and the [tour of heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
const promptTxt = document.getElementById('prompt-txtbox') as HTMLInputElement;
        console.log(promptTxt.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to create form with plain javascipt/jquery, you can use [Template form](https://angular.io/guide/forms) and [Reactive form](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) that angular provide to do the same.

A lot of example documentation/video in available for the same.

This seems like something you can also achieve by simple model binding but learning the correct way once will prepare you handle complex forms and build them quickly.